# hbm2ddl not working for some entity class in old claimed working source code

Tags: mysql, hibernate, reverse-engineering, hibernate-mapping, hibernate-tools

We have received claimed working source code. In code, all the entity model classes (hbm2java) are auto generated by `Hibernate Tools 4.0.0` (checked by generated class java docs). We are trying to perform reverse engineering to generate database schema from models with mysql databse.

MySQL :  5.1.46-community
MySQL Connector :  mysql-connector-java-5.1.46
Hibernate : Hibernate3

Here we are facing many errors:

```
Too many key parts specified; max 16 parts allowed
```

I am pasting the code of one such Entity class for which we are getting above error

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "ABC")
public class Abc implements java.io.Serializable {

    private AbcId id;

    public Abc() {
    }

    public Abc(AbcId id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    @EmbeddedId
    @AttributeOverrides({
            @AttributeOverride(name = "a", column = @Column(name = "A", nullable = false)),
            @AttributeOverride(name = "b", column = @Column(name = "B", nullable = false, length = 10)),
            @AttributeOverride(name = "c", column = @Column(name = "C", nullable = false, length = 2)),
            @AttributeOverride(name = "d", column = @Column(name = "D", nullable = false)),
            @AttributeOverride(name = "e", column = @Column(name = "E", nullable = false, precision = 12)),
            @AttributeOverride(name = "f", column = @Column(name = "F", nullable = false, precision = 12)),
            @AttributeOverride(name = "g", column = @Column(name = "G", nullable = false, length = 400)),
            @AttributeOverride(name = "h", column = @Column(name = "H", length = 400)),
            @AttributeOverride(name = "i", column = @Column(name = "I", nullable = false, length = 1)),
            @AttributeOverride(name = "j", column = @Column(name = "J", nullable = false, length = 2)),
            @AttributeOverride(name = "k", column = @Column(name = "K", nullable = false, length = 1)),
            @AttributeOverride(name = "l", column = @Column(name = "L", nullable = false, length = 100)),
            @AttributeOverride(name = "m", column = @Column(name = "M", length = 100)),
            @AttributeOverride(name = "n", column = @Column(name = "N", nullable = false, length = 23)),
            @AttributeOverride(name = "o", column = @Column(name = "O", nullable = false, length = 100)),
            @AttributeOverride(name = "p", column = @Column(name = "P", length = 23)),
            @AttributeOverride(name = "q", column = @Column(name = "Q", length = 100)),
            @AttributeOverride(name = "r", column = @Column(name = "R", nullable = false, length = 100)) })
    public AbcId getId() {
        return this.id;
    }

    public void setId(AbcId id) {
        this.id = id;
    }
}
```

This is a auto generated class by Hibernate Tools 4.0.0

Comment: Hi @parth : It will be help to get answers if you can mention some more details like the MySQL version, MySQL connector jar version, Hibernate Version which you are using